# Are Linear Quadtrees the most efficient way to store grid division data

Tags: compression, quadtree

Let's say you have a 32x32 grid that could be randomly subdivided using any of the block sizes below:

32x32, 16x16, 8x8, 4x4

How many times the grid is subdivided and in what way the subdivisions happen is determined at random.

Visually it could look something like this:

[image]

This type of data can be represented using a [quad tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

**My question is:**

If I was trying to use the least amount of bytes possible to represent the graph above, would a Linear Quad-tree be the most efficient way of doing this?

The only other alternative I could think of would be to make all the possible combinations of the graph, and use a single number to represent each combination.

So for the graph there are 4 levels of branching (32x32, 16x16, 8x8, 4x4) this would give us 4^0 + 4^1 + 4^2 + 4^3 possible combinations which is equal to 85 combinations.

Therefore the smallest way I can think of to store the graph would be to use 7 bits (1010101 is the number 85 in binary) to represent the possible combinations.

Would [Linear Quadtrees](http://www.csee.usf.edu/~tuy/Literature/QTree-Represent-CACM82.pdf) equal this in terms of storage efficiency, or would they take up more or less space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I normally don't answer my own questions, but seeing that this question is still getting views with no responses I'll give my answer.

After almost 2 days of research I now understand much better what Linear Quadtrees are.

A Linear Quadtree is simply an array representation of a quad tree written in a specific traversal order.

Basically just choose a specific "order" you want to read the quad tree in and save it's values in that order.

So for example in the graph used in the question there are 4 levels of stacks because there are 4 block-sizes (32, 16, 8, 4).

Each stack can be read in order.

So assuming the entire graph was filled with a 32x32 block the "root" of the tree (the first node we read) would be filled with a "1" to represent that we need that block while all the children of the root would be "0" as there are no more blocks needed because graph is full.

So the linear quadtree would look like this in binary "10000000000000.... (84 0's)"

This is obviously more than the 7 bits I mentioned in my question, but that's because there is no compression applied to this linear quad tree.

I really asked the wrong question. You need linear quad trees to represent a quad tree, so I really should have been asked "What is the best way to compress a linear quad tree", and the idea I gave in my question is the best way.

Create a lookup table with all the different quad-tree combinations and use a number to represent each combination.

Comment: Another effient way to store spatial data are [PH-Trees](https://github.com/tzaeschke/phtree). They work a bit like quadtrees, but depth is limited to 64. Also, they compress data in each node into a large byte[], for example stripping away the common prefixes of all coordinates in a given node.